# Como separar tabelas no mesmo HTML que usa JavaScript e apresentar o resultado em caixas

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Como separar tabelas no mesmo HTML que usa JavaScript e apresentar o resultado em caixas diferentes?

```
<HTML>  
<HEAD>  
<TITLE> Teste </TITLE>  

</HEAD>  

<BODY> 
                    <table border='2'>

<tr>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
    <!-- 
    var total = 4;  
    function soma(campo) {  
        if (campo.checked)  
           total -= eval(campo.value);  
       else   
           total += eval(campo.value);  
       document.sistema.total.value = total; 
   }  
   //-->  
</SCRIPT>
<TD>Rodrigo Nunes</TD>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="" name="sistema">  

<TD>1<input type="checkbox" name="valor" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"> </TD> 
<TD>2<input type="checkbox" name="valor" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"></TD>  
<TD>3<input type="checkbox" name="valor" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"></TD>  
<TD>4<input type="checkbox" name="valor" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"></TD>
<TD>Total de Faltas <input type="text" name="total" value=""></TD>

</FORM>
</TR>
<tr>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
    <!-- 
    var total1 = 4;  
    function soma(campo) {  
        if (campo.checked)  
           total1 -= eval(campo.value);  
       else   
           total1 += eval(campo.value);  
       document.sistema1.total1.value = total1; 
   }  
   //-->  
</SCRIPT>
<TD>Rodrigo Lima</TD>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="" name="sistema1">  

<TD>1<input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"> </TD> 
<TD>2<input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"></TD>  
<TD>3<input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"></TD>  
<TD>4<input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma(this)"></TD>
<TD>Total de Faltas <input type="text" name="total1" value=""></TD>

</FORM>
</TR>

</BODY>  
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problema

O teu problema atual está no fato de estares a fazer uso de duas funções JavaScript ambas com o mesmo nome:

```js
// Antes do teu primeiro formulário
var total = 4;  
function soma(campo) { /*...*/ }


// Antes do teu segundo formulário
var total1 = 4;  
function soma(campo) { /*...*/ }
```

## Solução

Uma solução rápida passar por alterar os nomes das funções e atualizar as chamadas às mesmas no `onclick`:

Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/bmqm7joc/).

```js
/* Para tabela com nome "sistema1"
 */
var total1 = 4;

function soma1(campo) {
    console.log(campo.checked);
    if (campo.checked) total1 -= eval(campo.value);
    else total1 += eval(campo.value);
    document.sistema1.total1.value = total1;
}

/* Para tabela com nome "sistema2"
 */
var total2 = 4;

function soma2(campo) {
    if (campo.checked) total2 -= eval(campo.value);
    else total2 += eval(campo.value);
    document.sistema2.total2.value = total2;
}
```

---

## A *markup* do teu HTML

A tua *markup* de HTML está um pouco confusa e incorreta porque estás a usar as tags de abertura e fecho do formulário pelo meio da *markup* da tabela.

Segue uma versão aprimorada da tua tabela:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="" name="sistema1">
        <table border='2'>
          <tr>
            <td>Rodrigo Nunes</td>
            <td>1
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>2
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>3
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>4
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>Total de Faltas
              <input type="text" name="total1" value=""/>
            </td>
          </tr>            
        </table>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="" name="sistema2">
        <table border='2'>
          <tr>
            <td>Rodrigo Lima</td>
            <td>1
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>2
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>3
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>4
              <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
            </td>
            <td>Total de Faltas
              <input type="text" name="total2" value=""/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Recomendo que faças uso do [validador de markup da W3C](http://validator.w3.org/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para que possas receber *feedback* sobre o teu código HTML de forma a saberes se o mesmo se encontra correto. É importante ter a *markup* correta para que tudo funcione como esperado em todo os navegadores.

---

## Exemplo completo a funcionar

Em baixo segue exemplo a funcionar fazendo uso da *markup* de HTML sugerida bem como uso do JavaScript sugerido:

```js
var total1 = 4;

function soma1(campo) {
    console.log(campo.checked);
    if (campo.checked) total1 -= eval(campo.value);
    else total1 += eval(campo.value);
    document.sistema1.total1.value = total1;
}

var total2 = 4;

function soma2(campo) {
    if (campo.checked) total2 -= eval(campo.value);
    else total2 += eval(campo.value);
    document.sistema2.total2.value = total2;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="" name="sistema1">
                <table border='2'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rodrigo Nunes</td>
                        <td>1
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>2
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>3
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>4
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor1" value="1" onClick="soma1(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>Total de Faltas
                            <input type="text" name="total1" value=""/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>            
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="" name="sistema2">
                <table border='2'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rodrigo Lima</td>
                        <td>1
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>2
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>3
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>4
                            <input type="checkbox" name="valor2" value="1" onClick="soma2(this)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>Total de Faltas
                            <input type="text" name="total2" value=""/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```